# Como acceder al puerto 8000 para entrar al Dashoard de vue cli

Tags: vue.js, npm

Hola tengo un proyecto de **VUE CLI** en un servidor de **AWS** en una instancia **EC2**. Cuando atravez de mi consola ejecuto

> vue ui

Me levanta el servidor en el localhost:8000 intento acceder a el de esta forma.

my-ip:8000 pero no responde sin embargo si corro el comando

> npm run build -- --watch

me levanta el servidor en netword que si es accesible de esta forma.

my-ip:8080

Los puertos si están abierto para dar salida y entrada.

Necesito el dashboard para poder instalar plugins y dependencias.

soy nuevo en vue cli

Esto es lo que obtengo cuando corro solo vue ui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: PRimero que todo no necesitas el dashboard para agregar plugins y dependencias. Eso lo haces con npm i y los paquetes que correponda. Mas alla de eso, cuando corres npm run build no estas corriendo lo mismo que al hacer vue ui. Vue ui levanta en otro puerto, no en el 8000. podrias mostrar la pantalla de salida que te sale al correr vue ui?

Comment: Listo. lo que quiero es poder acceder al servidor del dashboard desde intenet.

Comment: No se puede. No se expone y no sabria como exponerlo. Esta hecho solo para usarlo local. Es solo de desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

prueba así: 
`vue ui -H 0.0.0.0`

En teoría así le dices que escuche en todas las interfaces de red.